# how to make plot where curves may overlap?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm trying to make a plot similar to this one

[image]

Because there are curves that completely overlap each other, I like how he puts legends right on the curve, so he can plot so many curves without causing a mess, and have a separate figure shows what these legends stand for.

When I tried to make this plot in Matlab but I don't know how to make legends like this. And the double log with grid is a complete mess too.

How can I make this plot using either matplotlib or Matlab? Is matplotlib more flexible?

Comment: you can do this with `annotate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `annotate`, this should get you 90% there:

```
x = np.linspace(0,1000)
y = x ** -2

figure()
ax = gca()
ax.loglog(x,y)
ax.grid(True)
ax.grid(True, which='minor')

ax.annotate('a1', (x[15], y[15]),
            backgroundcolor='w',
            color='b',
            va='center',
            ha='center',
            bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", color='b'),)
```

[`annotate` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) and [examples](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html#plotting-guide-annotation).  Getting the circles might be tricky.  If you really want to use circles, I would suggest submitting a feature request on github.  (It looks like a few hours of digging into mpl guts to add ellipse bounding boxes).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you can make plot just with the axis object `ax.loglog(x,y)`.